# How to POST JSON from Powershell to a PHP script

Tags: php, json, powershell

I'm trying to send a JSON object to a PHP script with Powershell, and have that PHP script simply return what it gets as JSON...

In Powershell I'm doing this:

```
$a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
$a.Add(@{
    'prop1' = 'something'
    'prop2' = 'something else'
});

$a.Add(@{
    'prop1' = 'green'
    'prop2' = 'blue'
});

$b = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
$b.Add(@{
    'prop1' = 'another'
    'prop2' = 'yet another'
});

$b.Add(@{
    'prop1' = 'red'
    'prop2' = 'black'
});


$json = @{
    'first' = $a
    'second' = $b
} | ConvertTo-Json;

$json
```

At which point `$json` is a String like this:

```
{
    "second":  [
                   {
                       "prop2":  "yet another",
                       "prop1":  "another"
                   },
                   {
                       "prop2":  "black",
                       "prop1":  "red"
                   }
               ],
    "first":  [
                  {
                      "prop2":  "something else",
                      "prop1":  "something"
                  },
                  {
                      "prop2":  "blue",
                      "prop1":  "green"
                  }
              ]
}
```

Then I POST a `Invoke-WebRequest` with `$json` as the body:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Post -Body $json).Content;
```

The target is this PHP5 script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode(array("POST" => $_POST, "GET" => $_GET));
?>
```

But the response is just empty:

```
{"POST":[],"GET":[]}
```

I've tried getting PHP to just echo back a static string, which works fine, but can you see anything wrong with how I'm POSTing/accepting/responding here? I'm stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question.

The Powershell side was eventually:

```
$json = @{
    'a' = $a
    'b' = $b
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
```

So `$a` and `$b` are both arrays of custom objects as in my original question, and `$json` is a `Hashtable` that becomes a string via `ConvertTo-Json`

When using `Invoke-Webrequest` with `-ContentType 'application/json'` PHP doesn't receive a populated `$_POST` array. I had to read in the raw input in my php script like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

Then the result of `Invoke-WebRequest`, `$web`, has the JSON string as its Content property. Or I could use `Invoke-RestMethod` instead and the return type is a `PSCustomObject`

Another problem I overcame was that my real JSON string had special characters, requiring me to add `charset=UTF-8`